# Docker Toolbox creates machine(VirtualBox 5.1.20) but can't reach it successfully

Tags: docker, virtualbox

Recently decided to play with Docker, but I don't wanna change OS, way of working, etc... So I learned from documentation that there's a way to get docker functionality on Windows 7. Now I have installed VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox. But when I try create `default` machine, which Toolbox needs for working with Docker, it fails. Machine is created, but because of some obscure reason for me, Toolbox can't work with machine properly. Here's below screens that'll give clear picture: [image][image]

Comment: Try regenerating the tlc certificates by running `docker-machine regenerate-certs default`

Comment: didn't work out